# use babel-loader and less-loader together some include not working

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

### Description

when i only use babel-loader or no less file import webpack is normal.

but when i import less the include in babel-loader is not working or set the include in modules.rules[0] is throw Error

### Webpack Config

```
module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: [{
            loader: "babel-loader",
            options: {
                presets: [
                    ["@babel/env", {
                        targets: {
                            ie: "11"
                        },
                        corejs: "3",
                        useBuiltIns: "usage"
                    }]
                ]
            }
        }, "ts-loader"],
        exclude: /node_modules/
    }, {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: [{
            loader: "babel-loader",
            options: {
                presets: [
                    ["@babel/env", {
                        targets: { ie: "11" },
                        corejs: "3",
                        useBuiltIns: "usage"
                    }]
                ]
            }
        }],
        include: /html-entities/,
        exclude: /node_modules/
    }, {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [
            'style-loader',
            'css-loader',
            {
                loader: "postcss-loader",
                options: {
                    postcssOptions: {
                        plugins: [
                            [
                                "postcss-preset-env",
                                {
                                    browsers: "last 2 versions"
                                }
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            'less-loader'
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/
    }]
}
```

## Pictrue

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wogIS.png)